# How to query the database based on current day using Hibernate?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

I would like to retrieve database items based on the current day.

For that purpose I am trying to use the `day()` function as explained [there](http://www.coding-dude.com/wp/hibernate/hql-current-date/) and mentioned [there](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html).

I have a 'created' date field that is automatically filled when a new item is created in the table. It's configured using a model, like that:

```
@Column(name = "created", nullable = false)
@CreationTimestamp
private Date created;
```

I created a couple of items and the date is filled in the database as expected.

[image]

Now I am trying to call those items using a HQL query:

```
String hql = "" +
  "FROM Item as item " +
  "WHERE item.itemId = ?1" +
  "AND item.created = day(current_date())";
```

The problem is that this query is returning a NoResultException.

It's weird because I am using the `current_date()` function in other scenarios, e.g.:

```
String hql = "" +
  "FROM Item as item " +
  "WHERE item.itemId = ?1" +
  "AND item.createdAt >= current_date - ?2";
```

And it is working pretty well!

So I assume the issue is related with `day()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use this:

```
String hql = "" +
  "FROM Item as item " +
  "WHERE item.itemId = ?1" +
  "AND date(item.created) = current_date()";
```